# Build arraylist[s] from row of another arraylist[s] row[s]

Tags: java, arraylist

The title was hard to put out in enough detail for someone to click but essentially the problem is this.
A user enters the amount of students they have

Pictured is how it works essentially: [image]

Ignore the outputs under each input, thats my testing, it then prints out the average for each student.

What I need is to get the average of each test, a test is the input line, aka 10,12 is test 1 and 11,13 is test 2 and I would print the averages

I have Objects for Test and Student and have finally managed to get the student items printing averages but not the Tests as i am not sure how to get the first of each line.

[image]

Comment: Please add the source code as actual code, so that we can use it to validate our answers.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I managed to get my answer just now so all good.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys my question was unclear but I managed to get it.
Here is my answer.

```
for(int i = 0; i != testCount;i++) {
        Test t = new Test(i);
        ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
        for(Student stu: students) {
            temp.add(stu.getMarks().get(i).toString());
        }
        t.setTests(temp);
        tests.add(t);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is assuming all students take all tests

```
...
ArrayList tempM = new ArrayList();


for(int j = 0; j != s.length;j++ {
    Double mark = Double.parseDouble(s[j].toString())
    tempM.add(mark);
    Print(tempM.get(j).toString());
    stu.setMarks(tempM);

    Test test = null;
    if (tests.length < testCount) {
        test = new Test();
        tests.add(test);
    } else {
        test = tests.get(j);
    }
    // unknown ... test.addMark(mark)?  test.setMark(stu, mark)? ... something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're possibly going to run in to problems where one student may have taken more tests than another. ie. what should happen if you enter `11 22 33` and then `10 20 30 40` for the second student?

The simple solution, assuming that all students take the same number of tests:

```
for (int i = 0; i<students.get(0).length; i++){    //Loop over the number of tests
    int total = 0; 
    for (Student student : students){              //Loop over students
         total += student.getMarks[0];             //Add the value for that test result for that student
    }
    Print("results for test " + i + ": " + total/students.size());  //print average
}
```

If some students do more tests than others - then you'll need to change your solution to accommodate.